# Kubuntu only boots using Recovery Mode

Tags: boot, kubuntu, recovery-mode, 16.10

I recently installed Kubuntu 16.10 alongside Windows 10 on my Samsung 850 Evo SSD. Everything works great, except that Kubuntu will only boot using recovery mode. I've tried updating and rolling back the kernel, but that didn't seem to help. Any help you can give is appreciated.

Comment: You're likely to use the kernel boot option 'quiet splash'. That causes a lot of things to be hidden. Try disabling it and see if that tells you what the problem is during normal boot. (Edit /etc/default/grub, remove quiet splash from GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT. run update-grub, reboot)

Comment: Is this issue solved at all? I am having the same problem at the moment with Kubuntu 20.04